# gdebi: Prevent reinstalling the same version of a package?

Tags: apt, dpkg, version, deb

Is there a way to prevent `gdebi` (on the command line) from reinstalling the same version of a `.deb` file that is already installed?
For example, if I do

> ```
> $ gdebi -n example.deb
> Reading package lists... Done
> Building dependency tree
> Reading state information... Done
> Reading state information... Done
> (Reading database ... 568005 files and directories currently installed.)
> Preparing to unpack example.deb ...
> Unpacking example (13.6.0.10243651) over (13.6.0.10243651) ...
> Setting up example (13.6.0.10243651) ...
> ```

I see “`Unpacking example (13.6.0.10243651) over (13.6.0.10243651)`”. I would rather have gdebi do nothing if I already have the same version of the package installed. How can I achieve that?

For example, using `dpkg`, I can use the option `-E` (a.k.a `--skip-same-version`) for exactly this purpose:

```
$ dpkg -E -i example.deb
```

but `dpkg` doesn’t install dependencies.

I’m open to any workarounds. The only things I need are

- the ability to automatically install dependencies and
- a way to prevent reinstalling the same version of a package.

---

Note: I [previously asked this question on Launchpad](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdebi/+question/658069) (without response).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `apt install`: when given the filename of a package file, **with a path**, it will behave in the same way as `gdebi` if the package isn’t already installed with the same version, but it will skip installing the package if the installed version is identical to that contained in the given file.

```
apt install ./example.deb
```

Comment: Whoops, how embarrassing. For some reason, I thought apt only handles repositories.

Comment: No need to feel embarrassed, it’s a relatively new feature. I think it was introduced in `apt` 1.1 (so it’s new to Debian 9 effectively).